# Two tables referring to each other

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a simple social network app with records about users and their friends.
i.e. User with ID 1 has friends with IDs 2, 3. User with ID 2 has friends with IDs 1, 3, 4. etc.
Now I'd like to get records about that user and his friends.

I have created two tables

user

```
user_id | firstname | surname | age
```

friend

```
user_id | friend_id
```

And records something like this:

user

```
user_id | firstname | surname | age 
1       | Nikola    | Misic   | 22
2       | Stefan    | Ilic    | 23
3       | Dragan    | Jovic   | null
```

friend

```
user_id  | friend_id
    1    |    2
    1    |    3
    2    |    1
    3    |    1
    3    |    4
```

user_id and friend_id are foreign keys both pointing at user_id in user table.

Relationship looks like this:
[image]

I'm not sure is something like this even possible, I have worked with 3 tables, two tables connected through a composite table.

Comment: yes it's perfectly possible and a relatively common thing to need to do.

Comment: So the only thing left for me is to structure the query. But I'm not completely sure how.

Comment: "the query". I'm sure you'll end up needing lots of queries on this table. But anyway, you haven't said what you want this query to return. The friends? The user _and_ their friends? Something else? Have you tried to write such a query? It would not be difficult if you have got some basic SQL knowledge.

Comment: I.e. I would have in my PHP code something like $_GET['userid'], and then I would like to get data (user_id, firstname, surname, age) of all of his friends where (selected user) user_id = $_GET['userid']. 
I need data of his friends.

Comment: Off the top of my I head, I think it's `select * from users u inner join friends f on u.user_id = f.friend_id where f.user_id = ?` - ? would contain the userid parameter from `$_GET["userid"]`

Comment: Often times 1 table will join to a different table multiple times.  Each join (foreign key) would represent a different join to that same table.  you just have to alias each join so the engine can keep the references straight.  Soo.... Users and relations... I may join users to relations twice once for the owner of the relationship, and other time for the friend friend of the relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proposed relationship, as you've described it (a table with two foreign keys to columns in 1 other table) is perfectly possible and a relatively common thing to need to do.

In terms of querying a user's friends, based on what you said in the comments I think it's:

```
select 
  u.* 
from 
  users u 
  inner join friends f 
    on u.user_id = f.friend_id 
where 
  f.user_id = ?
```

`?` would contain the userid parameter from `$_GET["userid"]`

Comment: I feel ashamed right now. I have learned how to join tables, but I have never seen only two tables where one of them is composite. I have been 
working only with 3 tables. Thank you, I think this should work, but I'll test it today.

Comment: Do you have any idea how could I get friends of friends, those who are two steps away from the chosen user but not directly connected to the chosen user?

Comment: yes, just add another "join" from the "friends" to the "friends of friends" again using the IDs to link them via the "friends" table. In this join though, the "friend" will be identified by the "user_id" in the friends table, and the "friend of friend" will be the "friend_id" in the friends table. Try it, if you aren't sure please ask a new question and I can provide a detailed answer.

Comment: I think I did it

`select 
  u.*
from 
  user u 
  inner join friend f 
    on u.user_id = f.friend_id 
   inner join friend ff
        on f.user_id = ff.friend_id
        where ff.user_id = 4 AND u.user_id <> 4;`

Comment: I tried this `SELECT 
      DISTINCT u.*
   FROM 
      user u 
    INNER JOIN friend f 
    ON u.user_id = f.friend_id 
     INNER JOIN friend ff
        ON f.user_id = ff.friend_id
   WHERE ff.user_id = 20 AND u.user_id <> 20;`
And it works but I get users who are directly connected to the chosen user too. I just want to get friends of friends and they can't be directly connected to the current user. Help here?

Comment: As i said earlier, please ask a new question - this is an extension of what you originally requested and deserves a new question rather than a load of code jammed into comments. Post a new question, link to it here and I'll be happy to help.

Comment: I posted new topic [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43913201/friends-of-friends-sql-query) IIf you ahve time please check it :)