# 'friends of friends' SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

This question is related to previous one. You can check my first post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43848439/two-tables-referring-to-each-other)

I'm trying to pull data from a user table and I need 'friends of friends', those who are two steps away from the chosen user **but not directly connected to the chosen user**

I tried with this query:

```
select
 u.* 
 from user u 
     inner join friend f 
     on u.user_id = f.friend_id 
       inner join friend ff 
       on f.user_id = ff.friend_id 
 where ff.user_id = {$user_id} AND u.user_id <> {$user_id};
```

I didn't know how to pull users who are not directly connected to the chosen user. I get all friends of friends of the current user, but I *also* get direct friends of the current user.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to exclude the ones who are direct friends as well as being friends-of-friends. I've rearranged the table aliases so it's a bit clearer (to me, anyway) what's being retrieved:

```
SELECT
    u.*
FROM
    user u
    INNER JOIN friend ff ON u.user_id = ff.friend_id
    INNER JOIN friend f ON ff.user_id = f.friend_id
WHERE
    f.user_id = {$user_id}
    AND ff.friend_id NOT IN
    (SELECT friend_id FROM friend WHERE user_id = {$user_id})
```

It also removes the need to exclude the user ID being queried.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. You need to add a where condition that excludes those who are directly related:

```
select u.* 
from user u 
inner join friend f on u.user_id = f.friend_id 
inner join friend ff on f.user_id = ff.friend_id 
where ff.user_id = {$user_id} AND u.user_id <> {$user_id};
      AND not exists 
          (select f2.friend_id 
           from friend f2 
           where f2.friend_id = ff.friend_id 
                 and u.user_id = f2.user_id)
```

The extra `not exists` clause that I added to your query verifies that the second degree friend is also not a first degree friend.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a non-correlated subquery, which retrieves the ids of the direct friendships of `{$user_id}`, and exclude these users from the final result:

```
select u.* 
from user u 
inner join friend f on u.user_id = f.friend_id 
inner join friend ff on f.user_id = ff.friend_id 
where ff.user_id = {$user_id} AND u.user_id <> {$user_id}
      AND u.user_id not in (
           select directFriend.friend_id 
           from friend directFriend
           where directFriend.user_id = {$user_id})
```